# Como forzar "Indexing data"?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pyqt, postgis

los que usáis qgis3 sabréis que al poner una capa en edición e intentar modificar alguna geometría, aparece una pantallita con el texto "Indexing data", alguien sabe que se esta haciendo exactamente??? necesito forzar eso vía python.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, se coge la capa y layer.dataProvider().forceReload()